# Using S3FS node module for image uploading to amazon s3 how can I retrieve the image urls from s3?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I wrote this function to handle uploading images to amazon s3 using s3fs node module

```
var fs = require('fs');
var multiParty = require('connect-multiparty'),
    multiPartyMiddleware = multiParty();

var S3FS = require('s3fs')
var s3fsImp1 = new S3FS(process.env.BUCKET_NAME, {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
});

module.exports = function(app, express) {
  app.use(multiPartyMiddleware)

  app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    var files = req.files
    var fileCount = Object.keys(req.files).length
    var fileUploadCount = 0
    for (var file in files) {
      (function(file) {
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
        s3fsImp1.writeFile(file.name, stream).then(function() {
          fileUploadCount++;
          fs.unlink(file.path, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              res.send(400)
            }
          });
          if (fileUploadCount === fileCount) {
            res.send('successful uploading').status(200);
          }
        });
      })(files[file])
    }
  })
}
```

And it's working fine for the basic application of uploading images to amazon s3. However I haven't figured out how to return the image urls so I can
1. store reference to the image urls in a db
2. use/display the images on the client

How can I modify this function to retrieve the image urls after sending them to s3?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the library does not have that functionality. But it have a function call getPath that could help.

```
var s3fsImp1 = new S3FS(process.env.BUCKET_NAME, options);
var fsImplStyles = s3fsImp1.getPath(file.name);

// Change eu-west-1 for your region
var url = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + fsImplStyles;
```

Hope that helps